# Why only discrete labels are used for (semi-)supervised VAEs?

Tags: semi-supervised-learning, vae

I've noticed all semi-supervised VAEs assume discrete (categorical) labels to encourage disentangled representation learning in VAEs.

e.g.,

- Kingma, Durk P., et al. "Semi-supervised learning with deep
  generative models." Advances in neural information processing systems
  27 (2014).
- Maaløe, Lars, et al. "Auxiliary deep generative models."
  International conference onmachine learning. PMLR, 2016.
- Ilse, Maximilian, et al. "Diva: Domain invariant variational autoencoders." Medical Imaging with Deep Learning. PMLR, 2020.
- Klys, Jack, Jake Snell, and Richard Zemel. "Learning latent subspaces in variational autoencoders." Advances in neural information processing systems 31 (2018).

What is restricting the labels to be discrete for these applications?

I understand marginalizing out w.r.t. continuous labels is intractable, but AFAIK this is needed in case of unlabeled data.

For fully supervised case, I do not see the reason for restricting the use of continuous labels.